# Error while connecting Nodejs with LDAP in GCP cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, ldapjs

I am getting the below error while connecting to LDAP using nodejs in GCP cloud function

Error:
TypeError: options (object) required at Object.createClient

Index.js

```
exports.helloWorld = (event, context) => {
  const gcsEvent = event;
  var username = ***;
  var password = ***;
  console.log(`hello world`);
  var ldap = require('ldapjs');
  var client =ldap.createClient(username, password)({
   url: 'LDAP://...'
    }) 

client.bind(username, password,  function(error){
   if(error){ 
      console.log("error");
        } 
    else{ 
    console.log("Connected to ldap");
   } 
})
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
 "author": "sang",
  "description": "LDAP Binding for node.js",
   "dependencies": {
    "ldapjs": "^0.7.1"
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`var client =ldap.createClient(username, password)({ url: 'LDAP://...' })`

shouldn't it be like

`var client =ldap.createClient({ url: 'LDAP://...' })`

`createClient` take Object as an argument while you are providing username and password..

Reference [npmdoc](https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-ldapjs/build/apidoc.html#apidoc.element.ldapjs.createClient)

[image]